# MODX не видит файлы из админки

Tags: modx

Проект на MODX, после переноса, из админки не видны файлы, только папки и они не открываются. Если открыть файловый менеджер, то там такая надпись "Ни один файл не попадает под заданный фильтр."

Как это профиксить?

Версия MODX: Revolution 2.2.11-pl (traditional)

Comment: Добрый день. Вы имеете ввиду файлы-ресурсов не отображаются у вас в админке modx (вкладка "файлы-ресурсы", если я не ошибаюсь)? И какой Modx? Это надо сразу указывать, там много особенностей бывают, потому так сразу не ответишь.

Comment: У меня вкладка называется просто "файлы" (ресурсы | элементы | файлы), не css ни изображения, вообще ничего не отображается. MODX Revolution 2.2.11-pl (traditional),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конфиг модикса правили после переноса?  ( core/config/config.inc.php )

там есть такие строчки:

```
    /* PATHS */
$modx_core_path= '/path/to/modx_doc_root/core/';
$modx_processors_path= '/path/to/modx_doc_root/core/model/modx/processors/';
$modx_connectors_path= '/path/to/modx_doc_root/connectors/';
$modx_manager_path= '/path/to/modx_doc_root/manager/';
$modx_base_path= '/path/to/modx_doc_root/';
$modx_assets_path= '/path/to/modx_doc_root/assets/';

/* HOST (used for command-line PHP stuff) */
$http_host='yoursite.com';
```

Возможно, в этом проблема.

http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/administering-your-site/moving-your-site-to-a-new-server

Comment: Большое спасибо, проблема была в не внимательности, $modx_base_path - не поставил в конце / и $http_host не увидел и не исправил

Comment: Большое спасибо, долго бы сам искал, а оказывается в $modx_base_path путь не поменял, после переезда на другой хостинг